# How can I include external Python scripts while executing their codes in Quarto?

Tags: python, execution, evaluation, quarto

I am rendering a Quarto markdown as a parent file (`test.qmd` in the MWE). By way of rendering, I am trying to include an external Python script (`lm.py`) in the parent file while executing the Python code, and refer to the result of the code (`model` in `lm.py`) in the parent file. However, I face a `NameError` as shown below, and I am unable to access the result from the parent file:

```
Executing 'test.ipynb'
  Cell 1/2...Done
  Cell 2/2...ERROR: 

An error occurred while executing the following cell:
------------------
print(model.summary())
------------------

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_18968\3590939978.py in <module>
----> 1 print(model.summary())

NameError: name 'model' is not defined
NameError: name 'model' is not defined
```

Then, how can I include an external Python script while executing its codes when I render a Quarto markdown file?

## MWE

### `test.qmd`

````
---
format: pdf
execute:
  cache: false
---

```{python}
#| echo: true
#| eval: true
#| file: lm.py
```

```{python}
print(model.summary())
```
````

### `lm.py`

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd

mtcars = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('mtcars').data

model = sm.formula.ols('am ~ cyl + mpg', data = mtcars).fit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, that `file` chunk option comes with `knitr` render engine. But as you are using python code chunk, Quarto will try to render the qmd document with Jupyter. Hence `file` is not working and therefore, you are getting that `NameError`.

You can try the following as a workaround where you need to use the quarto extension [`include-code-files`](https://github.com/quarto-ext/include-code-files) to include code from an external script and use the [`%run`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#line-magics) jupyter line magic to evaluate codes from an external file.

````
---
format: pdf
execute:
  cache: false
jupyter: python3
filters: 
  - include-code-files
---

```{.python include="lm.py"}
```

```{python}
#| echo: false
%run lm.py
```

```{python}
print(model.summary())
```
````

---

[image: include and run from external py file]

---

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I confirmed your solution works on my environment!